# Convert complex object into dataframe - python

Tags: python

I have this object in python `ibrary ib_insync`:

```
>>> contract_details
0    Stock(conId=250100000, symbol=‘AAPL’, exchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='AAPL', tradingClass='AAPL'

Name: contract, dtype: object
```

How can I convert it into a data frame with the following columns?

```
conId, symbol, exchange, currency, localSymbol, tradingClass
```

Thanks

Comment: you have one object of type Stock, of multiple ? With one a dataframe seems useless

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of `Stock` then you can build a dataframe with them like this

```
values : list[Stock]
variables = ["conId", "symbol", "exchange", "currency", "localSymbol", "tradingClass"]
df = pd.DataFrame([[getattr(stock,attr) for attr in variables] for stock in values], 
                  columns=variables)
```